# UWP Httpclient postasync in background task with json string

Tags: json, uwp, httpclient, windows-10-universal, background-task

I would simply like to post some json to an api from a background task in my UWP app and get back the response to read it out. My background task is constantly failing with

> Platform::DisconnectedException ^ at memory location 0x077FEE74.

I tried many ways to get it work with things from the internet but only slightly adjusting the failure. Without the code I can execute the background task perfectly.

Here the code:

```
public async void Run(IBackgroundTaskInstance taskInstance)
        {
            _deferral = taskInstance.GetDeferral();

HttpClient aClient = new HttpClient();

            aClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            aClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("text/javascript"));



        Uri theUri = new Uri("https://m.xxxx.com/api/v4/session?expand=account,profile)");

StringContent theContent = new StringContent("{ \"keep_login\": true, \"id\": null, \"username\": \"zumbauser\", \"password\": \"zumbapw\" }", Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");


        HttpResponseMessage aResponse = await aClient.PostAsync(theUri, theContent);

        if (aResponse.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("This is outpuuuuuuuuuuuuuut: " + aResponse.ToString());
        }
        else
        {
            // show the response status code 
            String failureMsg = "HTTP Status: " + aResponse.StatusCode.ToString() + " – Reason: " + aResponse.ReasonPhrase;
        }

_deferral.Complete();
        }
```

The Json I am trying to imitate looks something like this:

> {"keep_login":null,"id":null,"username":"zumbauser","password":"zumbapw"}

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Which web API are you trying to call?

Comment: I'm using system.net.http cause StringContent is only available for that. How can I rewrite it for Windows.web.http ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be preferrable to use [windows.web.http.httpclient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.web.http.httpclient) for UWP apps since it supports wide range of Languages. See table from the [reference](https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2015/11/23/demystifying-httpclient-apis-in-the-universal-windows-platform/#lvhrrbpflgUT5jJr.97)

Now for StringContent. Windows.Web.HttpClient as HttpStringContent which is similar to StringContent in `System.Net.Http.HttpClient`

This is a snippet for example but make sure you read the reference.

```
Uri theUri = new Uri("https://m.xxxx.com/api/v4/session?expand=account,profile)");
HttpStringContent content = new HttpStringContent("{ \"keep_login\": true, \"id\": null, \"username\": \"zumbauser\", \"password\": \"zumbapw\" }", Windows.Storage.Streams.UnicodeEncoding.Utf8, "application/json");
var client = new HttpClient();
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(theUri, content);
```

So to complete your Method it will be

```
public async void Run(IBackgroundTaskInstance taskInstance)
{
    _deferral = taskInstance.GetDeferral();
    HttpClient aClient = new HttpClient();
    aClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
    aClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("text/javascript"));
    Uri theUri = new Uri("https://m.xxxx.com/api/v4/session?expand=account,profile)");
    HttpStringContent content = new HttpStringContent("{ \"keep_login\": true, \"id\": null, \"username\": \"zumbauser\", \"password\": \"zumbapw\" }", Windows.Storage.Streams.UnicodeEncoding.Utf8, "application/json");
    HttpResponseMessage aResponse = await aClient.PostAsync(theUri, content);
    if (aResponse.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("This is outpuuuuuuuuuuuuuut: " + aResponse.ToString());
    }
    else
    {
        String failureMsg = "HTTP Status: " + aResponse.StatusCode.ToString() + " – Reason: " + aResponse.ReasonPhrase;
    }
    _deferral.Complete();
}
```

**Note**: I tried the same with one of my APP in a background task and it works fine. only case it failed was when i tried to send huge data i got Not enough memory available error.

Good Luck and Happy Coding.

Comment: Thanks. Trying it now in variations. The "MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue" though is also part of the system.net.http api. VS2015 suggested me to change it to Windows.Web.Http.Headers.HttpMediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue. Will report back...

Comment: Exception thrown: 'System.IO.FileLoadException' in mscorlib.ni.dll
The program '[14704] backgroundTaskHost.exe' has exited with code 1 (0x1). That's all i get when i add the code. without the code it runs fine. :( There seems to be some other issue too...

Comment: Are you loading something from a File Here?

Comment: No. Nothing. That's the weird part. The background task is completely empty, besides the code. Has it something to do with the stream that needs a certain memory access?

Comment: Are you serializing Json from a Class object using Newtonsoft Json? If yes, then try to uninstall the package and install it. I had the same issue around 2 months back and doing this fixed my problem.

Comment: I had it installed before now that you are saying it but de-installed it after again. Will try to reinstall and then delete again...

Comment: After installing and deinstalling the nuget package for Newtonsoft Json the code runs sort of in the background task. I can tell that by the Debug writelines that i put before my method which was'nt executed before. Nevertheless i still don't get a response from the "postasync". Still getting this only on mobile device and on pc.: The program '[11828] backgroundTaskHost.exe' has exited with code 1 (0x1).
Exception thrown: 'System.Exception' in mscorlib.ni.dll

Comment: Hi! Somehow your code does not work for me. Please take  a lokk to my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54759390/exception-thrown-system-typeloadexception-in-unknown-module-in-uwp-background

Answer (score 1):

I know this might sound silly, but which `HttpClient` are you using? The one from `System.Net.Http` or the one from `Windows.Web.Http`? Try switching to the other one, it might help

Comment: I'm using system.net.http cause StringContent is only available for that. How can I rewrite it for Windows.web.http ?